# Map and Switch in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, jsx

I have a bit of a pickle, I have a React Function Component and i need to `map` and then `switch` inside my JSX.

I know i should attempt to do this outside/before the return statement but i can't seem to figure it out because the rendered component is dependent on an array passed through the component props.

Below is what i am trying to achieve inside my return statement

```
{(() => {
  files.map((file, index) =>
    let type = getFileType(file)
    switch(type){
      case 'image':
        return (
          <div className="item">
            <img src={file}/>
          </div>
        )
      default:
       return;
    }
  })()
}
```

I am obviously overlooking something important, i have been at it for a while and can't seem to get it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what does files array look like

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong there. Please read [ask] and provide a clear description of the *problem* (as opposed to just what you want to achieve) and a [mcve]

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: The file array is not the issue but to answer your question, it contains a list of file URLS. An example would be `['http://example.com/image/png']` while the `getFileType ` function returns the the type of the file, in this case `image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` from the Immediate-Invoked Function. Try like below.

```
{(() => {
  return files.map((file, index) => {
    let type = getFileType(file);
    switch (type) {
      case "image":
        return (
          <div className="item">
            <img src={file} />
          </div>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  });
})()}
```

Comment: Thanks Amila, your code  is the same as mine. The problem is, react throws an error on the lines `let type = getFileType(file)` and `switch(type){`.

Comment: Quatban Taco, I have fixed the syntax issues now, check again!

Comment: Your update does not throw another error. This solves my issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import React from "react";



const files = ["file01.img", "file02.other", "file03.img"];


const getFileType = (file) => {
    if (file.endsWith(".img")) return "image";
    return "other";
};



export default function YourComponent() {

    return (

        <div>

            { files.map( (file, index) => {
                
                let type = getFileType(file)
                
                switch (type) {
                    case 'image':
                        return (
                            <div className="item">
                                <p>image</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    default:
                        return <p>other</p>
                }
                
            } )}

        </div>

    );

};
```